# Ranorex button "Pressed" action seems not working

Tags: ranorex

I am very new at Ranorex, in fact I just starting to use the software this week. Everything is self-taught and online researches. My company automation engineers does not use Ranorex, so no help from them.

Currently company uses Ranorex version 6.1, I know it is old (hence no one uses it) and I dont think we can update it to the newer version without someone say so.

That being said, my issue is I was able to use Ranorex Spy to get the path for the "Open" button within the file explorer window: `/form[@title='Open']/button[@text='&Open' and @pressed='True'].`

However, although button is set to @pressed='True', but it does not seems that the button is been pressed.

Here is the screenshot in case my question is not clear.
Note: we use in house automation software in conjunction with Ranorex.

Image:
https://postimg.cc/tY1SVEn1

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to change the path to

```
/form[@title='Open']/button[@text='&Open']
```

I assume you don't have any other buttons with the text '&Open'

Comment: thank you for trying help me out. I worked the solution over the weekend. Turns out I should created an Object button "Open" in our automation software/Ranorex instead of using Ranorex path along.